# LinkedIn People search through keywords python

Tags: python, web-scraping, search, linkedin-api

I want to search for people on LinkedIn. I have the name of the person, current organization name, and contact details like email and phone.
I don't want an exact search but I want my module to give some search results related to my keywords.

I have an alternative way with the help of **googlesearch** package but want to know is there any other more accurate way.